# intern serve command is not working after reporters added in intern.js

Tags: intern

I have installed intern globally and on command prompt 'intern serve' commands works fine. However after adding reporters property in intern.js if I run 'intern serve' command then nothing happens and command stuck as below saying "Running runner tests…".

D:\start>intern serve

Running runner tests…

Here is my intern.js file

```js
// Learn more about configuring this file at <https://theintern.github.io/intern/#configuration>.
// These default settings work OK for most people. The options that *must* be changed below are the packages, suites,
// excludeInstrumentation, and (if you want functional tests) functionalSuites

define({
    // Default desired capabilities for all environments. Individual capabilities can be overridden by any of the
    // specified browser environments in the `environments` array below as well. See
    // <https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-capabilities> for links to the different capabilities options for
    // different services.
    //
    // Note that the `build` capability will be filled in with the current commit ID or build tag from the CI
    // environment automatically
    capabilities: {
        'browserstack.selenium_version': '2.45.0'
    },

    // Browsers to run integration testing against. Options that will be permutated are browserName, version, platform,
    // and platformVersion; any other capabilities options specified for an environment will be copied as-is. Note that
    // browser and platform names, and version number formats, may differ between cloud testing systems.
    environments: [
        { browserName: "chrome", platform: "WINDOWS" }
    ],

    // Maximum number of simultaneous integration tests that should be executed on the remote WebDriver service
    maxConcurrency: 2,

    // Name of the tunnel class to use for WebDriver tests.
    // See <https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-tunnel> for built-in options
    /*tunnel: 'BrowserStackTunnel',*/

    // Configuration options for the module loader; any AMD configuration options supported by the AMD loader in use
    // can be used here.
    // If you want to use a different loader than the default loader, see
    // <https://theintern.github.io/intern/#option-useLoader> for more information.
    loaderOptions: {
        // Packages that should be registered with the loader in each testing environment
        packages: [
            { name: "dojo", location: "node_modules/dojo" },
            { name: "dojox", location: "node_modules/dojox" },
            { name: "dijit", location: "node_modules/dijit" },
            { name: "showcase", location: "dist/src/showcase" },
            { name: "common", location: "dist/src/common" },
            { name: "technical-topics", location: "dist/src/technical-topics" }
        ]
    },

    // Unit test suite(s) to run in each browser
    suites: [ 'tests/**/*.js' ],
    tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

    // Functional test suite(s) to execute against each browser once unit tests are completed
    functionalSuites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/functional' */ ],

    reporters: [
        { id: 'Runner', filename: 'tests/reporters/Runner/report.html' }
    ],

    // A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis. Set to `true`
    // to completely disable code coverage.
    excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a several issues here:

- The message "Running runner tests...' is only emitted by the Combined reporter, not the Runner reporter.
- The Runner reporter is intended to output to the console; giving it an HTML filename will just output text to an HTML file (it won't generate an HTML report).
- The reporter config doesn't actually do anything when you're running `intern serve` because intern in `serve` mode is just serving files (not running tests).

Is your `intern.js` file in `tests\`? Intern assumes the project directory looks like:

```
D:\start
  tests\
    intern.js
  node_modules\
    intern\
```

When running `intern serve` in `D:\start`, intern will look for its config file in `tests\intern.js`.

Comment: Yes my directory structure is same as you mentioned. My intern.js file is in tests folder. "intern serve" command works properly without reporters property in intern.js. If I add reporters property to intern.js then only "intern serve" stops working. I have tried with other reporters also but not working

Comment: Could you post the entire project (or at least a simplified subset of it) somewhere? I'm curious about what's going on here, because the `reporters` property doesn't do anything in 'serve' mode, and even if it did, the output you're seeing isn't from the Runner reporter.

Comment: This issue reproduces even with basic intern tutorial also. I have shared basic setup here. If I remove reporters property from intern.js then only intern serve works.

Repository: https://github.com/shuklendu/intern-tutorial

Comment: `intern serve` is working in all cases. The problem is that since you're setting the reporter to JUnit, or redirecting the output to a file, you're not seeing the status messages (which are typically emitted by the Runner reporter). In any case, changing the reporter setting is not useful when you're running `intern serve`, because Intern isn't doing anything worth reporting on in that mode (other than serving files). To use a custom reporter setup and show property output in 'serve' mode, include both the custom reporter and Runner in the reporters list.